# Problems running an android application in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

While trying to run an Android app in Eclipse, I get the following message: Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead

Please help me solve this issue

I'm using jdk1.7 
and sdk r20.0.3

Answer (score 2):

The Android SDK expressively requires JDK 6, you are using the wrong version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the old version of Java SE 5/ JDK 1.5 or Java SE 1.6, Download Either Java 5 or Java 6.

Java 5 - Java 1.5 [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html)

Java 6 - Java 1.6 [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html)
(Choose According to your operating System, Once you are done installing JDK, Go to "Your_project">Properties>Java Compiler for "Compiler compliance level:" choose 1.5 Apply the changes and re-run the project If you are using Eclipse then you can follow Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> JDK compliance -> Change it to the one you had installed.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to uninstall your java version.

Simply, go to 
"Your_project">Properties>Java Compiler
and for "Compiler compliance level:" choose 1.5

Apply the changes and re-run the project

Answer (score -1):

You can find the latest versions of Java SE here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately he won't need the latest.. he will need the Java 1.6 JDK in order to work on android..

Answer (score -1):

```
Right click on project and
select Android Tools
select Fix Project Properties

and Clean Your Project...
```

Answer (score -1):

If u are using SDK r20.0.3 then u have to update ADT pluging as well into Eclips. You can do this easily via

Eclips/help/Market

Comment: anybody reading the SDK System requirements before using it? http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html